# How can I safely cut this thin stock with a small angle on a right tilting table saw?

Tags: table-saw, safety

I am replacing the meeting rail on some wood windows due to damage. I need to make a a roughly 36" strip that is this cross-section: 
[image]

How can I safely cut this on a right-tilting table?  It's also important to keep the angle consistent since it interfaces with a meeting face.

My initial idea is to make the cut using 3/4" stock using a thin push-stick. But, this seems potentially dangerous with the blade tilting towards the fence.

[image]

Comment: Feather boards are something else to consider for any future similar cuts. Here there'd be two feather boards (one pushing the stock in, the other down) and you'd use a long push stick that keeps your hand well clear of the blade. If your stock fence extends well past the blade you should for safety also install a secondary fence that ends in line with the blade's rear edge.

Comment: Move the fence to the other side of the blade and flip the stock over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut the bevel on a wide board, then set the fence to 3/4 and rip off the work piece with a straight blade.  Hold the large offcut when making the cut.  Flip the work piece so the wide edge is up and referencing off the middle of the fence, not sliding under it.

Or

Get a piece of stock much longer than you need, stop your cut when you are past the length you need but well before the end of your stock.  (Turn off the saw and wait for the blade to spin down.  Don't try to back it out.)  Then crosscut the piece you need off of the extra long stock.

Or

Determine your cut distance for the work piece on the left of the blade (use a temporary stop-block), then slide the fence against the large offcut on the right of the blade.  Make the cut holding the offcut against the fence.

Answer (score 1):

You could hot glue a straight piece of stock onto the part that will be cut. Then it will be extended from the fence and you can safely use a push stick on that extension part.

Likewise, a jig that holds the part such that you can use a De-Sta-Co type clamp to hold it down and then you push on the jig.

I mostly use a thin, but tall, push stick.